# search in database table by multiple column that maybe not set

Tags: mysql, where-clause

i have a database table with any column. and there is 3 form input in UI page, that a user can search a value in table by these inputs. the user can insert value for one of column (inputs), Two of columns or all of them. means its possible that one or two of inputs value be null and user don't use them for his search.
how to create the search query? because the following code have a problem. if user don't insert the value of all of 3 column, this query will take error.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM insurance WHERE nationalCode=:nationalCode AND insuranceNumber=:insuranceNumber 
AND insuranceType=:insuranceType;";
```

in other words, i need to search in table across 3 columns if value of 3 these columns have define by user else if user have insert value for 2 of columns search will do by these two columns & if user have insert value only for 1 of column search will do by that 1 column.

Comment: Have you tried `OR` in place of `AND` ?

Comment: So what is the value of :insuranceType if it is not set?

Comment: Dear @ O.Jones OR in not useful for my gold. because i need search by all of user inputs if the user insert values to all inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user did not insert a value, say for `nationalCode`, I assume the you pass `NULL` (or an empty string?) as `:nationalCode` and in this case your condition should be:

```
nationalCode = :nationalCode OR :nationalCode IS NULL
```

or:

```
nationalCode = :nationalCode OR :nationalCode = ''
```

So for all the columns the statement should be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM insurance 
WHERE (nationalCode = :nationalCode OR :nationalCode IS NULL)  
  AND (insuranceNumber = :insuranceNumber OR :insuranceNumber IS NULL)   
  AND (insuranceType = :insuranceType OR :insuranceType IS NULL);
```

Comment: tanks for your answer. i tried your offer but this query don't work. i think because by use your Query mySQL search for columns with null value in database table.

Comment: @HadiTaj the query doe not search for nulls. It checks if the parameter values that you pass, like `:nationalCode` are null. What value do you pass to the query when a user does not provide a value for `nationalCode`?

Comment: tanks for your answer. i tried your offer but this query don't work. i think because by use your Query mySQL search for columns with null value in database table. for example (by use your query) if user insert "nationalCode" and don't define the value of "insuranceType" and "insuranceNumber", then mySQL will search for records that have user entry value for nationalCode column and dont have value for insuranceType & insuranceNumber Column.  i want to find rows that have value for all of columns but the user mybe don't define value some of them.

Comment: if(isset($_POST["nationalCode"])){
    $nationalCode=$_POST["nationalCode"];
}else{
    $nationalCode=null;
}

Comment: @HadiTaj if the user did not define the value of "insuranceType" and "insuranceNumber" then `:insuranceNumber IS NULL` and `:insuranceType IS NULL` will both return true and the only condition in the statement will be: `where nationalCode = :nationalCode`.

Comment: so tnx for your help so i should find the problem that cause your offer query don't work.

Comment: yes sir. i search for problem in my codes that take error by your offered query. but i dident find any thing. your query dont solve my problem. when i use your query and fill one of inputs then submit form to search appear an error : Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in.

Comment: i can put my codes here . do you want too see my codes? i will edit your answer  and add my codes that use your offered query.

Comment: @HadiTaj *Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in* is not a MySql error, so it does not come from my query. You must fix your php code.

Comment: @HadiTaj don't edit my answer with code that is not mine. For any clarifications you should edit your question, but as I mentioned in my previous comment, the error that you get is from your php code and not a MySql error.

Answer (score -1):

Dear @forpas i have used your query and don't have succeed. but with tiny change in your offerd Query a have arrived my gold.
i used both of your code :
nationalCode = :nationalCode OR :nationalCode = ''
and
nationalCode = :nationalCode OR :nationalCode IS NULL
indeed i changed your suggested Query as followin:

```
        $query="SELECT * FROM insurance WHERE 
    (nationalCode=:nationalCode OR :nationalCode IS NULL OR :nationalCode='') AND
    (insuranceNum=:insuranceNum OR :insuranceNum IS NULL OR :insuranceNum='') AND
    (insuranceType=:insuranceType OR :insuranceType IS NULL OR :insuranceType='');";
```

so tanks for your help.